# Write SQL statements to create a table called MyGraph that can store any directed graph - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, directed-graph

I have to create sql statements to store this directed graph in my table. I need to return all source vertices in your table and then a statement that returns all edges, such that the source id is larger than the destination. I think I have most of the code completed, but I'm not sure what to make the vertices? I know the "source" numbers the problem refers to are 5, 7, 3, 11, 8 and the "destination" numbers are 11, 8, 2, 9, 20.

[image: here is the problem and graph I need to create]
[image: here is the code I have so far]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this site so I will try not to use screenshots again.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table graph1(s int ,d int);

insert into graph1 values(5,11);
insert into graph1 values(11,2);
insert into graph1 values(7,11);
insert into graph1 values(11,9);
insert into graph1 values(11,10);
insert into graph1 values(3,8);
insert into graph1 values(3,10);
insert into graph1 values(8,9);
insert into graph1 values(7,8);
```

output queries:

```
select distinct m.s from graph1 m where m.s not in (select n.d from graph1 n );

select m.s,m.d from graph1 m where m.s>m.d;
```